# Communicate between fragment and fragment dialog

Tags: android, dialog, fragment, communication

I researched on SO about communicating between fragment and fragment dialog, and I found that setTargetFragment and an interface is an approach. But I get this error when I try to setTargetFragment.

The method setTargetFragment(Fragment, int) in the type Fragment is not applicable for the arguments (SettingsDetailsFragment, int). I haven;t use fragments until now and I'm new on android. 
So i have this fragment:

```
   public class SettingsDetailsFragment extends Fragment implements
        NoticeDialogFragment.EmailChangedListner {

        public void emailUpdateFromDialog()
        {
         DialogFragment modifyEmailFragment = new ModifyEmailFragment();
        //here is where i get the error
        modifyEmailFragment.setTargetFragment(this, 0);`enter code here`

        modifyEmailFragment.show(getActivity().getFragmentManager(),
            "email");
  }
}

  // class where i have the interface
  public class NoticeDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {
    public interface EmailChangedListner {
    public void emailChanged(String text);
  }
```

}

```
 // the dialogFragment
 public class ModifyEmailFragment extends DialogFragment {

   @Override
   public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

    // Get the layout inflater
    LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();

    // Inflate and set the layout for the dialog
    // Pass null as the parent view because its going in the dialog layout
    final View v_iew = inflater.inflate(R.layout.email_dialog, null);

    builder.setView(v_iew)

            // Add action buttons
            .setPositiveButton(R.string.modifyBtn_settings,
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                            EditText userEmail = (EditText) v_iew
                                    .findViewById(R.id.modifyEmail);
                            boolean validateEmail = BookMeUtils
                                    .validateEmail(userEmail.getText()
                                            .toString());

                            if (validateEmail == false) {
                                BookMeUtils.enterValidEmail(getActivity());
                            }

                            if (!(userEmail.getText().toString().length() == 0)) {

                                if (validateEmail == true) {
                                    Fragment parentFragment = getTargetFragment();
                                    ((EmailChangedListner) parentFragment)
                                            .emailChanged(userEmail
                                                    .getText().toString());
                                }
                            } else {

                            }
                        }
                    })
            .setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel_r,
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            ModifyEmailFragment.this.getDialog().cancel();
                        }
                    });

    return builder.create();
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the import for `Fragment` in your `SettingsDetailsFragment` class. Is it importing `android.support.v4.app.Fragment` or `android.app.Fragment`.

Possibility is that you are setting `Fragment` of `android.support.v4.app` as the target of DialogFragment which is of `android.app`.

Comment: ok I tried to modify with android.app , now I can use setTargetFragment but i have other problem in other class... I have an adapter that when i call settingsDetailsFragment now whant to return Fragment not  return SettingsDetailsFragment.newInstance(position);

Comment: But i managed to solve the poblem wth the answer below But thanks for the tip i didn;t know that are problems between android.support.v4.app and android.app.fragment

Answer (score 1):

Your fragment will set listener and implement EmailChangedListner :

```
public class SettingsDetailsFragment extends Fragment implements
            EmailChangedListner {

            public void emailUpdateFromDialog()
            {
             DialogFragment modifyEmailFragment = new ModifyEmailFragment();        
            modifyEmailFragment.setListener(SettingsDetailsFragment.this);

            modifyEmailFragment.show(getActivity().getFragmentManager(),
                "email");
            }
       }
```

Dialog Fragment will have interface and an object of listener :

```
// the dialogFragment
 public class ModifyEmailFragment extends DialogFragment {

   EmailChangedListner listener;

   public void setListener(EmailChangedListner listener) {
        this.listener = listener;
   }

   @Override
   public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

    // Get the layout inflater
    LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();

    // Inflate and set the layout for the dialog
    // Pass null as the parent view because its going in the dialog layout
    final View v_iew = inflater.inflate(R.layout.email_dialog, null);

    builder.setView(v_iew)

            // Add action buttons
            .setPositiveButton(R.string.modifyBtn_settings,
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                            EditText userEmail = (EditText) v_iew
                                    .findViewById(R.id.modifyEmail);
                            boolean validateEmail = BookMeUtils
                                    .validateEmail(userEmail.getText()
                                            .toString());

                            if (validateEmail == false) {
                                BookMeUtils.enterValidEmail(getActivity());
                            }

                            if (!(userEmail.getText().toString().length() == 0)) {

                                if (validateEmail == true) {
                                    Fragment parentFragment = getTargetFragment();
                                    listener.emailChanged(userEmail
                                                    .getText().toString());
                                }
                            } else {

                            }
                        }
                    })
            .setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel_r,
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            ModifyEmailFragment.this.getDialog().cancel();
                        }
                    });

    return builder.create();
   }


  public interface EmailChangedListner {
    public void emailChanged(String text);
  }

}
```

Comment: ok i understand but i modified in my dialogFragment EmailChangedListner listener;

   public void setListener(EmailChangedListner listener) {
        this.listener = listener;
   } with SettingsDetailsFragment listener;

 public void setListener(SettingsDetailsFragment listener) {
  this.listener = listener;
 } and added ((EmailChangedListner) listener)
            .emailChanged(userEmail
              .getText().toString());